# How to get each uploaded images in dropzone.js and store in different variables in php or laravel before storing

Tags: php

Please am using dropzone.js and i am trying to get each image so that i can store them in different columns in the same row in a database, e.g

```
$image1 = $request->file('file');
$image2 = $request->file('file');
$image3 = $request->file('file');
```

The way it works now is that the multiple images are uploaded and stored into new rows like this:

```
public function storePfphotos(Request $request)
{  
    $img = $request->file('file');
    $folder = 'portfolio';

    $imgname = $img->getClientOriginalName();

    $img->move($folder, $imgname);
    $request->user()->pfphotos()->create([
    'imgpath' => 'portfolio/' . $imgname,

]);
```

But I dont want that.
Can someone tell me how to go about it, am thinking an array might work but i really don't know

Comment: I am not laravel expert, but take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021086/laravel-5-attempting-multi-file-upload-requestfile-only-returning-last-fil

Comment: Thanks, i would read it up

Answer (score 1):

By default, I believe Dropzone sends multiple uploads as separate requests to your `storePfPhotos()` method.

You'll want to set the `multipleUploads` configuration value for Dropzone to `TRUE`.  This will send all the images in one request (as an Array) and you can then iterate through them and store them how you like.

http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-uploadMultiple

```
foreach($request->file('file') as $index => $file) {
   // in an array
   $files[] = $file;

   // or separate variables
   $file_name = 'file_'.$index;
   $$file_name = $file
}
```